# Can I get public graph API data without a token?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to display a list of public Facebook events that I post on a separate webpage so it's easier to keep updated - just update Facebook and the next call to the graph API shows my current events.

I've got the javascript SDK working on the page, but the graph API seems to always want an access token for me to request any data, even public stuff. I obviously don't want a user to have to log in to my web page just to see some events. Is there a way to request public event data without an access token? Or can I add a hardcoded access token that is only available for use by my Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and, no, you can't access public events without a token.
But yes, you can have an access token just to retrieve this (for instance, if you already have an app, you can use your user token for it).

My suggestion is that you access the graph api only once after you add/update your events, and store the result in a static place (json, db, static file, etc) so that you can easily show it when needed instead of making requests to the graph api every time.